# c# asp.net web api file existance not found using namespace

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-web-api, stream, namespaces

I hope I'm doing something wrong because to me at this moment it looks like what I'm doing is correct. First off I want to open a file using the name space.
Lets say I have this string:

```
string resource = "Middelware.DataResources.dba.Queries.getTest.sql"
```

Then I'm trying to open it using:

```
var stm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource)
```

But it doesn't work unfortunately. So I have been using this as a test case:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\text.txt"))
```

But for some reason it keeps returning false. I played around abit as well like using: "C:\\text.txt". But nothing happens.

I'm using visual studio 2017. And the class this is happening in is static.

So my questions:

1. Why cant file.exist seem to validate the test file exists?
2. Why is 
   var stm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource) not working, given that the namespace should be correct?

Hope some can help me with this silly problem.

Kind regards

Comment: Have you changed the type of the sql script to 'Embedded Resource' in the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer question 1: I had a typo..

Question 2 Is given in the comments. Let me quote:

> Have you changed the type of the sql script to 'Embedded Resource' in the IDE? – Matt 3 mins ago

Comment: You have a typo here too: Middelware.DataResources.dba.Queries.getTest.sql - Should read "Middleware" I'm guessing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing too much information so I'm guessing.

#### Read from file

From `File.Exists` [method reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx), the returned value can be:

> **true** if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, **false**.
>
> This method also returns **false** if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string.
>
> If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns **false** regardless of the existence of path.

You have already excluded some cases, so you should check whether the application has proper read permissions for the target file or its parent directory.

#### Read from assembly

Issues with resource streams are often related to:

1. Wrong resource name. Can be the upper/lower case, or an additional string put as prefix by Visual Studio compiler.
2. Resource not actually compiled in assembly

You can list all available resources in your assembly with:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```